# Lost HttpContext in a custom event

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting the 'Response is not available in this context error' calling the following function:

```
Private Sub ReloadPage(ByVal inNumber As Integer) Handles tempaux.Advertise
    'Response.Redirect("tope.aspx?dep=" & CStr(inNumber))
    Response.Write("<script>window.open('tope.aspx?dep= & CStr(inNumber)','topFrame');</script>")
End Sub
```

I've changed the line adding the System.Web.HttpContext.Current before Response.Write and I get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

To give some background: tope.aspx is, as you can see, opened in topframe. As soon as it loads it starts a CustomTimer object I've defined:

```
Public Class tope
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public funciones As funciones = New funciones
    Dim WithEvents tempaux As CustomTimer = Global.objCustomTimer

    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim inUserProfile As Int64
        Try
            tempaux.StartTimer()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'bla bla
        End Try
```

As you can see I've declared the CustomTimer in the Global.asax. The CustomTimer object raises an Advertise event every 5 seconds and passes 'inNumber' as a parameter for the tope.aspx page to refresh some label, a simple thing. CustomTimer is a class I made to manage the timer, it doesn't inherits any other class( For what I've learned in my search it has to inherit some httpthing but I'm not sure). I'm guessing that at some point the httpcontext is being lost (I've searched in google and I couldn't figure its lifecycle or whatever information that tells me why it 'dies). Can anyone help me to find out what is the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your timer exists outside of the tope page class, so it is possible that the timer event is firing after the response from the page is complete and there is no longer a HttpContext.Current instance.

It sounds like what you are trying to do is to change an advertising banner on a page every 5 seconds, once the page is loaded.  You need to do that using a javascript timer, which would fire every 5 seconds and make a request back to your web server for a new advertisement.

Comment: Hmmm I get it. The thing is that the time of 'refreshing' is got from a database and it can even be changed in runtime besides I have to reload the page giving it a parameter also got from a database. Mi idea was to manage everything with VB. Isn't there a way of 'creating an HttpContext' just as the application do when you click a button and then use Respose.Redirect?

I guess another option is to use AJAX but as I'm using Visual Studio 2003 I don't know if it is well supported.

Comment: You could try to create a HttpContext, but the Response would not go back to the user's browser, since it didn't initiate the request.  Based on the description in your question, I believe that javascript is what you need to refresh the ad.  If not, you'll need to provide more description.